# What is the typical usage of ElasticSearch in conjuncion with other storage?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, elasticsearch

It is not recommended to use ElasticSearch as the only storage from some obvious reasons like security, transactions etc. So how it is usually used together with other database?

Say, I want to store some documents in MongoDB and be able to effectively search by some of their properties. What I'd do would be to store full document in Mongo as usual and then trigger insertion to ElasticSearch **but I'd insert only searchable properties** plus MongoDB ObjectID there. Then I can search using ElasticSearch and having ObjectID found, go to Mongo and fetch whole documents.

Is this correct usage of ElasticSearch? I don't want to duplicate whole data as I have them already in Mongo.

Comment: That seems reasonable given your scenario. (I'm not sure how to measure correctness for your needs -- if you need the type of searches that ElasticSearch provides, then this could be an effective combination of DB and search engine).

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is for now to duplicate documents in ES.
The cool thing here is that when you search, you don't have to return to your database to fetch content as ES provide it in only one single call.
You have everything with ES Search Response to display results to your user.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use mongodb river take a look at [this post](https://coderwall.com/p/sy1qcw)
There are more issue then the size of the data you store or index, you might like to have MongoDB as a backup with "near real time" query for inserted data. and as a queue for the data to indexed (you may like to use mongodb as cluster with the relevant [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) suited for you application